# rep down without downvote or without unchecking it as answer

Tags: support, reputation, questions

I again came across a strange situation.
[image]
Here you can see my 2 rep down without any notification,
Its only 2 so it is clear that its not the case of revoking an OP's action of select this as answer in this case it should be 15 I guess.

So whats wrong going on ?

**NOTE**
The second part of image is latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the "summary" display which is showing the top 5 posts. Click on the "reputation" tab and it will be visible.

Or use my [reputation tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=260990&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=today&showflair=true) to see that it's [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940183/3940201#3940201) which has been downvoted.

Comment: Here if we get down vote it displays like -2 in red colored font.

Comment: @org.life.java: Well it still does if you look at the reputation tab, in my experience.

Comment: Thanks :) , But don't you think it should come to summary also, it comes in all case this is the first exceptional for me i guess

Comment: @org.life.java: Well the summary does say it's the "Top 5 posts" - i.e. the ones that have earned you the most reputation. It seems reasonable that it doesn't show a negative one in preference to a positive one.